# I am looking for an API that can provide all medicines that are sold in Pakistan. I have seen that chemists have a such kind of database?

Tags: api, sql

I am looking for an API that can provide all the medicines that are sold in Pakistan. I have seen that chemists have a such kind of database. What are some pointers?